# Find out how long the sql server service has been running, from t-sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'd like if its possible to work out from inside sql server how long sql server has been running.

Would like to use this in conjunction with one of the DMV's for unused indexes, but the counters are re-set every time sql server loads, so I'd like to know how useful they're going to be.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
SELECT
    login_time
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_sessions
WHERE
    session_id = 1
```

will give you a `datetime` for when the server was started.

Comment: i think i like this kludge better then the tempdb kludge. both look like they give the same result!

Comment: and I wouldn't even call this a kludge - but a method! ;-)

Comment: This is the exact time: SELECT sqlserver_start_time FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info.  The value tends to be slightly earlier than the sys.dm_exec_sessions method.

Answer (score 5):

To get it programmatically, you can run this script. It checks the creation time of your tempdb, since tempdb gets reinitialized every time Sql Server is started.

```
SELECT create_date 
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE name = 'tempdb'
```

To make it more intuitive, you can run the script below, which will tell you how many days and hours Sql Server has been running. Minutes and seconds information will be truncated. If you need that, modify the script to get it yourself.

```
SELECT 'Sql Server Service has been running for about '
+ CAST((DATEDIFF(hh, create_date, GETDATE()))/24 AS varchar(3)) + ' days and '
+ CAST((DATEDIFF(hh, create_date, GETDATE())) % 24 AS varchar(2)) + ' hours'
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE name = 'tempdb'
```

Source: [How long SQL Server has been running](http://www.haidongji.com/2007/05/07/how-long-has-my-sql-server-been-running/)

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT crdate FROM sysdatabases WHERE [name] = 'tempdb'`

The above will work on SQL Server 2000, 2005 and 2008.

The logic is that the result from the above SQL returns the created date of the tempdb database, which SQL Server recreates every time it is restarted. Hence, the created date of tempdb is the startup time of the server.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is super old, but Microsoft has added a new DMV with this information since this question was asked.

```
SELECT dosi.sqlserver_start_time
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info AS dosi
```

Answer (score 0):

Grabbed [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/3d7aa13d-61a7-48d2-ada6-2398b31feb39/)

```
USE Master
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @crdate DATETIME, @hr VARCHAR(50), @min VARCHAR(5)
SELECT @crdate=crdate FROM sysdatabases WHERE NAME='tempdb'
SELECT @hr=(DATEDIFF ( mi, @crdate,GETDATE()))/60
IF ((DATEDIFF ( mi, @crdate,GETDATE()))/60)=0
SELECT @min=(DATEDIFF ( mi, @crdate,GETDATE()))
ELSE
SELECT @min=(DATEDIFF ( mi, @crdate,GETDATE()))-((DATEDIFF( mi, @crdate,GETDATE()))/60)*60
PRINT 'SQL Server "' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),SERVERPROPERTY('SERVERNAME'))+'" is Online for the past '+@hr+' hours & '+@min+' minutes'
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses WHERE program_name = N'SQLAgent - Generic Refresher')
BEGIN
PRINT 'SQL Server is running but SQL Server Agent <<NOT>> running'
END
ELSE BEGIN
PRINT 'SQL Server and SQL Server Agent both are running'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple query works for versions before SQL Server 2005 as well as recent ones:

```
SELECT
 crdate AS startup,
 DATEDIFF(s, crdate, GETDATE()) / 3600. / 24 AS uptime_days
FROM master..sysdatabases
WHERE name = 'tempdb'
```

Comment: what is dot after number ?

Comment: The dot makes sure the constant is a decimal number to prevent integer division (which truncates any decimals).